# discord.js messaging a new channel

Tags: discord.js

hi im trying to make a counting game so my bot will count with people or check if they lose

```js
let count = 0
let timeout
client.on('message', ({channel, content, member}) => { 
    if (client.channels.cache.filter(c => c.name === 'counting').keyArray().includes(channel.id)){
    if (member.user.bot) return
    if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
        count++
        if (timeout) client.clearTimeout(timeout)
        timeout = client.setTimeout(
            () => channel.send(++count).catch(console.error),30000)
        } else if (member.id !== client.user.id) {
            const clonnedChannel = channel.clone({});
            clonnedChannel.send(`${member} you messed up`).catch(console.error)
            
            channel.delete();
            
            count = 0
            if (timeout) client.clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
    }
})
```

but it doesn't send you messed up message to the new cloned channel with error: `clonnedChannel.send is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GuildChannel.clone()` returns a `Promise` so you need to `await` `channel.clone`.

```js
let count = 0
let timeout
client.on('message', async ({channel, content, member}) => { 
    if (client.channels.cache.filter(c => c.name === 'counting').keyArray().includes(channel.id)){
    if (member.user.bot) return
    if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
        count++
        if (timeout) client.clearTimeout(timeout)
        timeout = client.setTimeout(
            () => channel.send(++count).catch(console.error),30000)
        } else if (member.id !== client.user.id) {
            const clonnedChannel = await channel.clone({});
            clonnedChannel.send(`${member} you messed up`).catch(console.error)
            
            channel.delete();
            
            count = 0
            if (timeout) client.clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
    }
})
```